# Is it okay to raise a previously instantiated exception, in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I have an exception class that I'm constantly raising with the same messages. This is how I currently have it structured...

```
class MyException(Exception):
  UNAUTHORIZED = 'UNAUTHORIZED'
  SOME_OTHER_EXCEPTION = 'SOME_OTHER_EXCEPTION'
  SOME_OTHER_THING = 'SOME_OTHER_THING'
  # ...

def func():
  # ...
  raise MyException(MyException.UNAUTHORIZED)
```

That is quite un-pythonic. I'm wondering if I could do something like this instead...

```
class MyException(Exception):
  UNAUTHORIZED = MyException('UNAUTHORIZED')
  SOME_OTHER_EXCEPTION = MyException('SOME_OTHER_EXCEPTION')
  SOME_OTHER_THING = MyException('SOME_OTHER_THING')
  # ...

def func():
  # ...
  raise MyException.UNAUTHORIZED
```

... which looks *a lot* cleaner.

I'm wondering if this is okay to do... is there any importance where an exception is instantiated?

Or am I approaching this whole thing incorrectly? Should I be doing something like this instead?

```
class MyException(Exception):
  pass

class UnauthorizedException(MyException):
  def __init__(self):
    super(UnauthorizedException, self).__init__('UNAUTHORIZED')

def func():
  # ...
  raise UnauthorizedException()
```

(In this case, I'd have about 10 different custom exception classes, which I think is a bit much, which is why I'm leaning toward my earlier idea.)

Comment: Why not do it like `ValueError`, and pass a string to `MyException`?

Comment: @PM2Ring - That's essentially what the first example seeks to do. I'm calling `MyException` again and again with the same string values, which is why I set them to class constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, exceptions have a `__traceback__` attribute storing the corresponding traceback. If you reuse the same exception object everywhere, that's going to overwrite `__traceback__` and mess with traceback inspection.

Additionally, reusing exceptions will also mess with exception chaining: `__context__` and `__cause__`. You are likely to see the wrong exceptions reported as the context or cause of reused exceptions.

---

Don't reuse exception objects. Rather than `raise MyException(MyException.UNAUTHORIZED)` or `raise MyException.UNAUTHORIZED`, you should go with the subclasses. It's a lot easier to do

```
except UnauthorizedException:
    ...
```

than it is to do

```
except MyException as e:
    if e.args != (MyException.UNAUTHORIZED,):
        raise
    ...
```